# AG-Grid: Make editable columns based on response from server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I need some help for work. The story goes like this:

I need to make the "Date" Column editable if Item-Id !== null;

We have a "view" where we have an inbox created with AG-Grid.
The inbox looks like this:

```
    ---| Item-Id | Date | Justification |---
    ----------------------------------------
    ---|         |24.05 | text          |--- 
    ----------------------------------------
    ---|    31   |25.05 | text 2        |---
    ----------------------------------------
    ---|    31   |25.05 | text 2        |---
    ----------------------------------------
    ---|         |24.05 | text          |---
    ----------------------------------------
    ---|         |24.05 | text          |---
    ----------------------------------------
    ---|    31   |25.05 | text 2        |---
    ----------------------------------------
```

To generate the column headers in AG-grid you have an object:

```
    public columnDefs = [
        {title: Item-Id, editable: this.editable()},
        {title: Date, editable: this.editable()},
        {title: Justification, editable: this.editable()}
    ];
```

...some code...

in the Get method I have something like this:

```
    http.get(data).subscribe(response(
        {
            ...some code...
            this.editableColumns(response);
        }));

    public editableColumns(item: any) {
        //this method need to return true or false;
        console.log(response); // [{itemId: null, date: "24.05", justification: "text"},{itemId: 31, date: "24.05", justification: "text"},...etc...}]
    }
```

I would very much appreciate your help.

p.s: you cannot make the cells editable by using methods like column["editable"] = true; It won't work. It needs to be a function that returns true or false.

Comment: I think what you want to do should be quite easy, but your code samples look a bit confused...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't really know the structure of Angular, but I think you want something as simple as this:

```
const columnDefs = [
    {
        headerName: 'Item-Id',
        field: 'your_id_field',
    },
    {
        headerName: 'Date',
        field: 'your_date_field',
        editable: function(params) {
            return params.node.data.your_id_field !== null;
        }
    },
    {
        headerName: 'Justification',
        field: 'your_justification_field',
    },
];
```

That will allow the `your_date_field` cell to be edited for rows where `your_id_field` is not null.

Modify as needed to get it to work in your code.

Comment: IT WORKED.THANK YOU SOO MUCH