# Angular Grid Ag-Grid, make Column Editable dynamically

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Well, the title looks quite similar to other posts:

[Angular Grid ag-grid columnDefs Dynamically change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31743534/angular-grid-ag-grid-columndefs-dynamically-change)

[AG-Grid: Make editable columns based on response from server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462154/ag-grid-make-editable-columns-based-on-response-from-server)

but I'm going to ask a slightly different question.

Now I have a bunch of columns stored in tableColumns variable.

Each column has a editable property.

For existing data, some columns are editable and some are not. This is achieved by below function. It is called when I define columnDefs.

```
checkEditable(columnName: string){
        var editable = false;
        this.configData.some((el) => {
          if (columnName == el.key.columnName){
            return el.editable == "Y";
          }
        });
        return editable;
      }
```

However, for newly inserted rows which got appended at the bottom of my grid, I want **all columns to be editable for this record only**.

This record can be identified by column isChanged = "inserted".

```
insertNewRow(){
    var newItem = this.createNewRowData();
    var res = this.gridOptions.api.updateRowData({add: [newItem]});

    var updatedColDefs = [];

    **//how can I update columnDefs here, so that all fields are editable for this record?**

    var col = this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(updatedColDefs);

  }

  createNewRowData(){
    var newData = [];
    this.tableColumns.forEach(item => {
      if (item.headerName == "isChanged") {
        newData["isChanged"] = "inserted";
      } else {
      newData[item.headerName] = "";
      }
    });

    console.log(newData);
    return newData;
  }
```

Most likely I will have to create a function to achieve this, but seems like I am unable to assign function to 'editable' property of the column? What would be the correct syntax?

Answer (score 2):

It's not your syntax, but the approach.

Below approach will work for you.

1. Make editable `true` for all columns.
2. For new rows you are inserting, have a flag to specify that the record is newly inserted. You already have that as `newData["isChanged"] = "inserted"`
3. Use `(cellEditingStarted)="onCellEditingStarted($event)"` event to check whether the currently editing record is `newly inserted` record or not.

   - If it is, then make it editable
   - If its not, then check if the current column is editable or not.

Check this code

```
 onCellEditingStarted($event) {
    if($event.data.isChanged != 'inserted' && $event.colDef.editable != true)
    // check property is used at column level to identify editable or not in above statement
        this.gridApi.stopEditing();
}
```

For reference (not exact what you want, but you'll get idea): [how to disable editing for only some rows in ag grid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291763/1417185)