# how to disable cell editing in gridApi when if data is existing in rows but i wanna back cell editing in empty rows

Tags: javascript

```
$scope.departmentGrid = {
  data: 'deplist',
  enableRowSelection: true,
  multiSelect: false,
  modifierKeysToMultiSelect: false,
  enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
  noUnselect: true,
  enableColumnMenus: false,
  enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
  columnDefs: [{
      field: 'depId',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      displayName: 'Department Id',
      width: 180
    },
    {
      field: 'depName',
      enableCellEdit: true,
      displayName: 'Department Name'
    }
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var cellEditable = function ($scope) {
        if ($scope.row.entity.depId === undefined)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    };
    $scope.departmentGrid = {
        data: 'deplist',
        enableRowSelection: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        modifierKeysToMultiSelect: false,
        enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
        noUnselect: true,
        enableColumnMenus: false,
        enableHorizontalScrollbar: 0,
        columnDefs: [
            {field: 'depId', enableCellEdit: true, displayName: 'Department Id', width: 250, cellEditableCondition: cellEditable},
            {field: 'depName', enableCellEdit: true, displayName: 'Department Name'
            }
        ]
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can handle this like below code:  you have to use editable
>   columnDefs property. editable will return a true or false according to
>   the condition. and you can manipulate the condition according to the
>   need of the requirement. if condition will return false then it will
>   disable the editing and vice versa.

```
columnDefs: [{
      field: 'depId',
      editable: (params)=>{return params.data["depId"] === '' }
      displayName: 'Department Id',
      width: 180
    },
    {
      field: 'depName',
      editable: (params)=>{return params.data["depName"] === '' }
      displayName: 'Department Name'
    }
  ]
```

Comment: @WaiGyi can you please create one stackblitz of your requirement. it would be helpful to make changes directly over there to help you quickly.

Comment: @WaiGyi please see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50341639/angular-grid-ag-grid-make-column-editable-dynamically . it might be helpful for you.